# Awaiting status update from API with React Hooks (useEffect)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to achieve the following:

Using React + React Hooks + useEffect

1. Make an API post request
2. Receiving an ID
3. Making another post request using the ID to get the status (Queued or Completed)

So basically

```
{
  id: "xxxxxxx",
  status: "queued"
}
```

Is what I get back. Now the processing time varies, but I want to periodically check if the status has changed from "queued" to "completed". And while it's not completed, I want to display a loading spinner.

What would be the best way to do this? Would this be possible with promises / async functions? Or do I have to use some kind of interval to re-check the status periodically?

I am basically trying to use this in React: https://docs.assemblyai.com/walkthroughs#authentication

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
// Mocks - after the 2nd attempt getStatus will return "done"
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
let attempt = 0;
const getId = async () => {
  console.log("getId");
  await delay();
  return { id: "id1" };
};
const getStatus = async (id) => {
  console.log("getStatus", { id, attempt });
  attempt += 1;
  await delay(1000);
  return {
    id,
    status: attempt < 2 ? "queued" : "done"
  };
};

export default function App() {
  const [id, setId] = useState();
  const [isDone, setIsDone] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const effect = async () => {
      const { id } = await getId();
      setId(id);
    };

    effect();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let cancelled = false;
    const effect = async () => {
      let { status } = await getStatus(id);
      while (status !== "done") {
        if (cancelled) {
          return;
        }
        await delay(1000);
        status = (await getStatus(id)).status;
      }

      setIsDone(true);
    };

    if (id) {
      effect();
    }
    return () => {
      cancelled = true;
    };
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>{isDone ? "Done" : "Loading..."}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note: this is simplified and does not cover error scenarios, but shows how this can be put together

[image: Edit suspicious-tesla-2ue0m0]

Comment: Thank you! I understand only half of this. So, generally speaking, there is no function or way to just wait for the value to change, you have to use some kind of delay and re-fetch for the data to evaluate it?

Comment: You could use a websocket to send status updates to your client, but with the API you describe I think polling is the simplest option